# Telerik kendoUI panelbar jumping

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-panelbar

all,

I'm having an issue when using the panelbar and animation. whe it expands, it 'jumps' a little at the bottom. My content inside the panel does have padding/margin at the bottom, which i need there to create separation. Anyone know how to make it quit jumping while still have padding/margin at the bottom of the content inside it?

Answer (score 0):

We also had this trouble with panelBar, and we solved it by adding css rule to a content in panelBar like this:

html:

```
<ul data-role="panelbar" >
      <li>
         <span><h3>Some text</h3></span>
      <ul class="category-content>
       <li> Some item </li>
      </ul>

      </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.category-content {
    width: 100%;
}
```